# Login failed for user 'xyz' - with new SQL Azure user account

Tags: database, authentication, azure

I created a new database user account in SQL Azure with the following scripted steps, however, changing my connection string (EF 4.1) from the "admin" login gives me a "Login failed" exception.  This is a WinForm "sandbox" app that WORKS when I use my Azure admin login.

[connected to master db]
CREATE LOGIN xyz WITH password='fakepassword';

[connected to DB where I want to add user - NOT master]
CREATE USER xyzuser FROM LOGIN xyz;

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'xyzuser';

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'xyzuser';

Why can I not login?  I seem to be doing all the correct steps.  I have SSMS 2008 (not SSMS 2008 R2), so I am doing all the user setup thru the Azure portal.

Thanks,
Randy

Answer (score 0):

How about try to assign the DBO to your user through the script

`EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'xyzuser'`

Comment: This did not solve the issue.  I seem to get the exception on the Login, which occurs BEFORE I actually attempt to access any objects (i.e.  Tables).

Comment: Can you please provide the details of the exception you got.

Answer (score 0):

For reference of others, I am answering my own question.

My problem was that I was setting up the connection string and using the "USER" as the "User ID" value.  This stems partly from the fact that I spend little time doing DBA activities in SQL Server.  Because my SQL command script was "CREATE USER xyzuser ...", I plugged "xyzuser" into the connection string as "User ID".  I know... Duh!  As soon as I used "xyz" as User ID from the "CREATE LOGIN xyz ...", everything worked.